# How to make date time field readable after getting response using RestFul webservice

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, web-services, rest

I am building a webapp using Restful webservice using angularJs + spring. Can anybody tell how to make date field readable in the UI ? Also, I am not getting the last field values that is 'STATUS'. Below is the code for the same.

Basic Entity class/ model class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="User",schema="test")
public class User implements java.io.Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Date creation_time;
    private Date last_update_time;
    private String email;
    private String mobile;
    private String status;

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID", unique = true, nullable = false) 
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Column(name="LAST_NAME")
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "CREATION_TIME", nullable = false, length = 19)
    public Date getCreation_time() {
        return creation_time;
    }
    public void setCreation_time(Date creation_time) {
        this.creation_time = creation_time;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "LAST_MOD_TIME", nullable = false, length = 19)
    public Date getLast_update_time() {
        return last_update_time;
    }
    public void setLast_update_time(Date last_update_time) {
        this.last_update_time = last_update_time;
    }

    @Column(name="EMAIL")
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Column(name="MOBILE")
    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }
    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @Column(name="STATUS")
    public String getStatus(String status){
        return status;
    }


}
```

Controller class

```
    @RestController
    public class UserController {

        @Autowired
        UserService userService;    
        private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserController.class);

         @RequestMapping(value="/users",method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")
         public List<User> getAllUsers() {   
          List<User> users=userService.getAllUserService();
          return users;
         } 
}
```

DAO interface

```
public interface UserDAO {
               public List<User> getAllUser();
     }
```

DAO Implementation class

```
@Component
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    Session session = null;

    private void assignSessionLocalVariable(){
        if(session == null || !session.isOpen()){
            try{                
                session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            }catch(Exception e){session = null;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

@Override
    public List<User> getAllUser() {
        List<User> user=null;
        assignSessionLocalVariable();
        if(session!=null){
            try{    
                   String q="from User";
                    Query query = session.createQuery(q);
                    user = query.list();    
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        session.close();
        return user;
    }

    public void closeSessionObjects(){
        if(null != session) session.clear();
    }
}
```

Service interface

```
 public interface UserService {
    public List<User> getAllUserService();
}
```

Service implementation class

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    UserDAO userDAO;

    @Override
    public List<User> getAllUserService() {
        return userDAO.getAllUser();
    }   
}
```

App.js

```
  var user=angular.module('userApp', ['']); 
    user.controller('userController',function($scope,$http){

        var urlBase="http://localhost:8080/UserDetail";

        $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        $http.get(urlBase+"/users")
            .success(function(data){
                 $scope.users = data;
            }); 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

[moment](http://momentjs.com/) is pretty awesome for formatting datetime

Example for your case:

Let's say the datetime looks like 2015-11-11T22:21:37+00:00. Obviously this does not look very readable. We can change it to something better by making a moment object and using the format function.

`moment(2015-11-11T22:21:37+00:00).format("MM/DD/YYYY")` would output 11/11/2015

Comment: As you can see in the app.js all the data is coming in the form of object then how to parse specific fields from this object and then send it back to the UI ?